# How to add unequal length named vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

This must be easy but I can't seem to make it work. I have two named vectors of unequal length:

```
x <- as.vector(c(5, 10,15,20))
names(x) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y <- as.vector(c(7, 12))
names(y) <- c("A", "D")
```

I want to add them and preserve the naming convention of the longest. I would like for x + y to yield:

```
A   B   C   D
12  10  15  32
```

I've tried making the lengths equal as suggested elsewhere and that allows the arithmetic but doesn’t preserve the naming convention. I've also tried things like:

```
z <- x[names(y)] + y
```

but that gets me the arithmetic but doesn't preserve structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `replace` to do this, matching the names of the two vectors:

```
x + replace(rep(0, length(x)), names(x) %in% names(y), y)
#  A  B  C  D 
# 12 10 15 32
```

This assumes the names of `x` and `y` are in the same order.

Alternately, you could do something like, which doesn't require the same ordering:

```
z <- x
m <- match(names(y), names(x))
z[m] <- z[m] + y
z
#  A  B  C  D 
# 12 10 15 32
```

Though neither of these are quite as concise as @RichardScriven's suggestion of using `tapply`, they are both a good deal more efficient on large vectors:

```
set.seed(144)
big.x <- runif(1000000)
names(big.x) <- paste("x", 1:1000000)
big.y <- big.x[sort(sample(1:1000000, 500000))]
sum.rscriven <- function(x, y) {
  z <- c(x, y)
  tapply(z, names(z), sum)
}
sum.josilber1 <- function(x, y) x + replace(rep(0, length(x)), names(x) %in% names(y), y)
sum.josilber2 <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x
  m <- match(names(y), names(x))
  z[m] <- z[m] + y
  z
}
system.time(sum.rscriven(big.x, big.y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  12.650   0.151  12.817 
system.time(sum.josilber1(big.x, big.y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.214   0.002   0.215 
system.time(sum.josilber2(big.x, big.y))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.180   0.003   0.182
```

Note that both proposed solutions are at least 50x faster than the `tapply` solution in this example (`big.x` of length 1 million, `big.y` of length 500k), since they perform a single vectorized addition instead of many smaller calls to `sum`.

Comment: I really like the one that uses `match()`.  Nice thinking

Comment: Very nice! Since I need not only the sum but the difference, I will use the match solution. Thanks. Ernie

Answer (score 6):

You can use `tapply()`

```
z <- c(x, y)
tapply(z, names(z), sum)
#  A  B  C  D 
# 12 10 15 32
```

Comment: Perfect, Richard. Have not used tapply before. Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One using `length<-` and `colSums`

```
colSums(rbind(x, `length<-`(y, length(x))[names(x)]), na.rm=T)
#  A  B  C  D 
# 12 10 15 32
```

Another using `merge` and `colSums`

```
colSums(merge(as.list(x), as.list(y), all=T), na.rm=T)
#  A  D  B  C 
# 12 32 10 15
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to maintain the ordering from `x`.